# How to return Umbraco 404 page when no content found in UmbracoVirtualNodeRouteHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm using `UmbracoVirtualNodeRouteHandler` to do use some custom logic to find my Umbraco Content. This works great except for when I don't find the content.
When I don't find content, I want to show the **Umbraco 404 page**.

```
protected override IPublishedContent FindContent(RequestContext requestContext, UmbracoContext umbracoContext)
    {
        var content = findMyContent();
        //attempt 1
        return content; //even if content is null
        //end attempt 1

        //attempt 2
        if(content == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "Blogpost not found");
        }

        return content;
        //end attempt 2
    }
```

Attempt 1 results in the default unstyled 404 page saying
 "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
[image: Default IIS 404]

Attempt 2 results in showing my custom error 500 page.
[image: Custom 500 Error Page]

**How do I show my custom Umbraco 404 page when I don't find content?**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the configuration in `umbracoSettings.config`?

You can configure a custom node for the 404 page by referencing the node ID, GUID or XPATH:

```
<errors>
    <error404>1234</error404>  
</errors>
<!--
The value for error pages can be:
* A content item's integer ID   (example: 1234)
* A content item's GUID ID      (example: 26C1D84F-C900-4D53-B167-E25CC489DAC8)
* An XPath statement            (example: //errorPages[@nodeName='My cool error']
-->
```

Comment: Yes, 404 page has been set up and works in normal scenarios, just not with UmbracoVirtualNodeRouteHandler

Comment: I don't think you should handle 404 in UmbracoVirtualNodeRouteHandler. The way I understand this is Umbraco handle the 404 automatically. If you want to code you own 404 handler you can create an IContentFinder and set it as the ContentLastChanceFinder. It's explained in details in the umbraco documentation : https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Routing/Request-Pipeline/IContentFinder

Comment: Thanks for that feedback. Community members on Umbraco Slack were directing me in the same direction. Personally, I think if I return `null`, it should go to the Umbraco 404 page I set, not the IIS 404. I'll be rewriting the `UmbracoVirtualNodeRouteHandler` to a `ContentFinder` to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you try to insert in the web.config <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />. Reference: https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using/ui-questions/8244-IIS7-404